# LibGDX Fullscreen Windowed mode has Border

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm trying to setup fullscreen windowed mode in my LibGDX desktop application, but the window is still decorated. Here is my code:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");
        config.width = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().width;
        config.height = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().height;
        config.fullscreen = false;
        new LwjglApplication(new EnvironmentTest(), config);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? The window looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a border going around the image. Also, the border continues onto the next monitor.

Comment: Windowed mode has a border thats the name. Border title bar, close, resize, minimize button.. That is windowed mode, but I  guess you just use a wrong term .

Comment: I suppose you have never heard of fullscreen windowed mode in games? Because in games, fullscreen windowed mode refers to a fullscreen window with NO border. This way its convenient to tab in and out of it and have it still be fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem make sure you have this line of code:

```
config.resizable = false;
```